# How to make an embedded view controller respond to Mac Catalyst UIResponderStandardEditActions

Tags: uikit

I have two view controllers. vc1 and vc2.

The following code is run

```
vc1.addChild(vc2)
vc1.view.addSubview(vc2)
```

The problem is that this doesnt seem to put vc2 in the responder chain. Actions like `override func copy(_ sender: Any?)` aren't called in vc2 when I do the copy command whereas if I add this to vc1 instead it IS called. It would seem

[The methods in this one dont work for me.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47914650/how-to-make-embedded-view-controller-part-of-the-responder-chain)
`NSApp.windows.first` is not for Catalyst. And `vc1.next` (nextResponder has been renamed in swift) is immutable.

Comment: We need a ***lot*** more information. Best is if you put together a [mre] (emphasis on *minimal*) so we can see what you're trying to do and then offer help with your implementation.